# Show time in agenda list

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Time can't show in time-agenda within org-mode

It shows like this:

[image: It shows like this:]

I want it show like this:

[image: I want it show like this:]

Comment: What settings have you tried that incorporate the `org-agenda-time-grid` variable?  http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html  Days without appointments are not going to display a time-grid.

Comment: I deleted some code in my "init.el" file and then it worked, maybe I have added some useless thing.

Answer (score 2):

I recently experienced the same issue. Although your issue may have had a different cause, I thought I would share my solution in case it my be useful for future readers.

In my case, I had the following setting in my custom agenda commands:

```
(org-agenda-prefix-format "○ ")
```

This gave me a minimalistic agenda where tasks were prefixed by `○`, and nothing else. However, this overrides the default format which includes a number of formatting characters that allow the prefix to display, among other things, the time, specified by the `%t` format character which displays "the HH:MM time-of-day specification if one applies to the entry".

I have since changed `org-agenda-prefix-format` as follows:

```
(org-agenda-prefix-format "○  %t")
```

which still gives me a minimalistic agenda view, but additionally displays time information if necessary. Here is a full list of formatting characters that work with `org-agenda-prefix-format`:

```
  %c   the category of the item, "Diary" for entries from the diary,
       or as given by the CATEGORY keyword or derived from the file name
  %e   the effort required by the item
  %l   the level of the item (insert X space(s) if item is of level X)
  %i   the icon category of the item, see `org-agenda-category-icon-alist'
  %T   the last tag of the item (ignore inherited tags, which come first)
  %t   the HH:MM time-of-day specification if one applies to the entry
  %s   Scheduling/Deadline information, a short string
  %b   show breadcrumbs, i.e., the names of the higher levels
  %(expression) Eval EXPRESSION and replace the control string
                by the result
```

For more details, see the documentation for `org-agenda-prefix-format`: `M-x describe-variable RET org-agenda-prefix-format RET`.